# is it foolish to use gmail with PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, google-apps

Soon I'll be launching my new site and i was planning on using gmail as the email server for things like registration and lost password.

I'll be using google apps (free version) so I can have admin@mydomain.com.

**Besides the 500/day limit are there any other potential problems with using gmail for this service?**

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why would you opt to use gmail as mailserver instead of your own exim/qmail/... setup? For every mail app i've built i've never had any trouble getting my mails where they should go

Comment: so as to avoid any issues of my server being marked as spam and becuase from what i've ready sending though gmail is less likely to get market as spam

Comment: I created a simple python hack to send email with app engine. You can view the source code at https://gist.github.com/3db0d51f55812a2057d6. It is a quick hack within an hour an not really well documented yet, but I guess if you are a programmer you can figure it out quickly.

Comment: well Alfred, what can i say - thanks for all your time on this one, i'll take a look when i've finished what im currently on and let you know how i get on - legend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 Years im using gmail apps + phpmailer, never had a problem (except the 500 limit as you mentioned).

Emails take (on my experience) not more than 1-2 seconds to be sent; Just remember to use ssl on port 465.

And noone of my emails is been market as a SPAM

Comment: Thanks daniel,
what kind of capacity/uses have you been using it for?
I'm building a web app which will be dependant on these emails, so i need good uptime etc but am not expecting to go even near the 500 mark

Comment: Actually i use it for an application that create estimates online and then send them via gmail as a pdf attachments, the biggest peak we had was around 100/150 per days. To be honest, i dont think that 500 emails would be a problem, but you should try out by yourself.. I never reached it myself so i cant tell ;)

Comment: ..as a side note, you could track how many email you send with one account via php and then, when youre near the 500 cap, use another account to send emails, and so on. For example, you create info@example.com, info2@example.com, info3@example.com... but this is more a trick than a solution, i wont suggest you that

Comment: 'Just remember to use ssl on port 465.' - the SSL thing might save one from snail-pace emailing IMHO. Am I right ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed SSL is required for gmail, so you can't choose to not use it.
By the way, using gmail's smtp (and any other external smtp) is slower than using the internal server smtp

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SSL connections are slow as hell.  Sending one email takes ~10 seconds.  I use Google Apps, but I only send out the occasional New User and Forgot Password emails, so it's not that bad.

Comment: Im using google apps with phpmailer since 2 years, never had a problem, email are been sent in about 1-2 seconds, not 10 ;)

Comment: SSl connection slow ? then what is recommended? tls ? So much interested to know .

Answer (score 1):

### Using google app engine instead of sending mail via gmail

I haven't used gmail with PHPMailer, but I don't think it is foolish. But if you ask me you are better of using google app engine to [send emails](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html). I realize this isn't a php solution, but I think to achieve what you want the google app engine documentation will fit your bill. That way you don't have the hard limit enforced on you and it scales very well.

> P.S: Google has a very generous free daily
>   [quota](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Mail): 
>   
>     **Mail API Calls 7,000 calls, 32
>   calls/minute**

### Learn basics of deploying an application to google app engine

Also a little [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfgO-LXGpTM) from Slatkin(<10 minutes) to learn the basics of deploying a app to Google App engine. When I saw this video I was sold to the power of app engine and python.

### Send email via Python's app engine SDK

Here you will find a little snippet which I directly copied from there documentation.

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

mail.send_mail(sender="Example.com Support <support@example.com>",
              to="Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>",
              subject="Your account has been approved",
              body="""
Dear Albert:

Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
access new features.

Please let us know if you have any questions.

The example.com Team
""")
```

Comment: for someone with a good understanding of php, how big a thing is it to learn enough about the app engine to use it for emails?

lots to learn?

Comment: @Haroldo I modified my post a little bit I would advice you to watch slatkin's video how to create a blog in 10 minutes and I guarantee you you are sold to Google app Engine.

Comment: If you already know and work with php, you'll need a couple of days to learn python (i mean, learn python just to send email, not the whole language at all).

Comment: I think it can be written in 1 day even of you don't have any programming experience at all. The video from google + documentation will get you started. You can read it within a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. We send through Gmail / Google Apps service and it has worked fine for us.